# Easy question: How do I search for apps on my S3?

Tags: search

I know (N00b) but I see the Google search bar for performing internet searches. But I don't see where a quick search for my phone's content is, like you would find on an iPhone by moving to the search screen. (Which searches through all of the phones content-contacts, apps, email, etc.)

Comment: I don't have an S3, just a generic Android 4 tablet, but my Google search bar (from the home screen) searches local apps _and_ the internet. You can touch the magnifying icon to select "All", "Web" or "Apps".

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold the menu button (button to the left of the physical home button). It will launch google now and if you enter the first letter of the name of an app it should start listing those apps, at least it does it on my galaxy s3.

[image]

Comment: Yep, and in the lower panel, make sure to select (scroll to the right) Phone.

Answer (score -1):

If you pinch inwards on the app list then the app lists minimize and can be rearranged.

Comment: This sounds very device specific, and I don't believe it correctly answers the question.

Comment: First, thank you for replying! Ok, my Google search from the default home screen does not list local apps (as clickable items) in the search results. For example the "clickpad" app IS listed, but solely as the Internet search item; not as it would on the iPhone as a local item which can be clicked on and opened. Does ICS or S3 have a search function which searches the device, first or only? Thanks! The pinch option is cool but the names are too small for me to read and find my wayward app. :)

Answer (score -1):

Found an app, this allows you to search your device for apps:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.startapp.quicksearchbox&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5zdGFydGFwcC5xdWlja3NlYXJjaGJveCJd